# Magic %qtconsole problem Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, qt, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, qtconsole

Hi guys I have a great problem: when i develop my model on jupyter notebook, i'm used to write the command:

`%qtconsole`

in order to test a little pieces of notebook before implementing them. I had to install a new jupyter environment as always done, but in this case if i run this cell nothing happen. If i write `!jupyter console` work, but I cannot write on the jupyter notebook because it appears as it is bsy with the console. How can i call a console connected to my jupyter notebook to test a little pieces of code? Thank you for the attention and the patience. Have a good day

Comment: Something to consider is are you sure you need the qtconsole? A lot of the interactions and abilities that the qt console used to provide are now baked in to Jupyter. In particular the newer generation JupyterLab adds a lot of new abilities. Second, you say you installed a new jupyter environment. Did you install the qtconsole there, too? Is this the same machine where `%qtconsole` was working the way you expected recently?

Comment: Third, is `%qtconsole` the only thing in your cell. I'm seeing in fresh Jupyter **without** installation of Jupyter Qt Console , putting `%qtconsole` in a cell with nothing else results in running instantly and nothing happening when I run it too. No feedback of any kind other than the cell showing as executed. However, when I run `!jupyter console` in a notebook in the fresh sitruation without jupyter console installed, I get the man page for jupyter. Does yours hang if you also put in `!jupyter gobblydegoo`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Wayne! Yes the machine is the same and logically I installed the qt console package. However when I run it in the cell nothing happen! The qtconsole is very important for me to test a little pieces of code before implementing them! I don't know how i can solve it because the console is foundamental for me

Comment: Problems that arise with a new instalation or version are hard to diagnose remotely. I mostly use the plain ipython console, but your approach does work for me, on a plain vanilla jupyter instalation. (no separate qtconsole).

Comment: Thank you @hpaulj. I think that is a problem with some package, but I cannot understand which. I found a txt where I signed all package installed on a previous version and if I install it in a new environment, the  console stars as well. I don't know what is happened with the new version released. For me there is a bug in Jupiter because new versions not are to start the qtconsole both on lung and macOS where I tried.